# Question about Radon Measures

Tags: measure-theory

This problem is from Folland Chapter 7 question 2
Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$,
Let $N$ be the union of all open $U\subset X$ such that $\mu(U)=0$. Then $N$ is open and $\mu(N)=0$

My question: Why can't we just use subadditivity to get that $\mu(N)\leq \cup \mu(U_\alpha)=0$, Why do we have to use inner regularity?(probably)?

Comment: Because $\{ U_\alpha \}_\alpha$ need not be countable.

Comment: This is what I needed. Is the measure assumed to be positive here?